# What are the best use cases scenario to use Spring Integration and Spring Batch? How they work together?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch to process CSV files as a batch process and SFTP adapters (Spring Integration) to download and upload files. Found Spring Documentation very helpful. But I am a little bit confused and curious about their best use cases.

So far my understanding, a monolith application can be broken down and integrated with another external system (FTP, email, queue, etc) using Spring Integration. What are the other use cases? Should I use Spring Batch with Spring Integration? What are the best practices?

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

There are no "best" use cases, it depends on the context. There is a whole chapter about how to use Spring Batch and Spring Integration together here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#springBatchIntegration.

I will let you decide when it is best to use them together depending on your requirement.